# Which Kendall's tau does stats::cor() use?

Tags: r, statistics, correlation

`stats:cor()` offers `"kendall"` as a method for computing a correlation coefficient.
Kendall's *Tau* actually comes in [three variants](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kendall_tau_rank_correlation_coefficient) **a** (no adjustment for rank ties), **b** (adjusted for rank ties) and *c** (suitable for rectangular as opposed to square tables).

Which one does `stats:cor()` use?

(Bonus: is there a package that allows for all three? [Kendall](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Kendall/index.html) does not appear to offer these choices.)

Comment: I am aware that there is a quite similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2557863/measures-of-association-in-r-kendalls-tau-b-and-tau-c) though careful study of the answers and comments reveals disagreement on whether tau a or tau b are implemented in cor().

Comment: You'll need to download the source for R from CRAN, then look for cov.c in the stats directory.  I don't read C so I can't answer the question, but that seems to be where the calculation is done.

Comment: thanks @BryanHanson – same here: I don't know C.

Comment: this question especially pertains to [qmethod](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/qmethod/index.html), a CRAN package for Q Methodology.
If anyone would be able to add a new tag `qmethod`, that would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cor(x, y, method="kendall") calculates Kendall's tau-b (adjusted for ties).

Most available software packages (e.g. cor(), Kendall()) all calculate Kendall's tau-b. The difference between Kendall's tau-a and tau-b is essentially the denominator. Specifically, for Kendall's tau-a, the denominator D=n*(n-1)/2, which is fixed, while for Kendall's tau-b, the denominator D=sqrt(No. pairs of Var1 excluding tied pairs)*sqrt(No. pairs of Var2 excluding tied pairs). The value of tua-b is usually larger than tau-a. I think Kendall's tau-c is rarely used.

I didn't see any packages for Kendall's tau-a, but it is not hard to implement in R.

Answer (score 2):

A little bit late, but here is a comparison:

```
> set.seed(1)
> n <- 20
> x1 <- sample(1:4, n, replace = T)
> x2 <- sample(1:4, n, replace = T)
> 
> abc <- c(DescTools::KendallTauA(x1,x2),
+          DescTools::KendallTauB(x1,x2),
+          DescTools::StuartTauC(x1,x2)) 
> names(abc) <- c('tau-a','tau-b','tau-c')
> abc
      tau-a       tau-b       tau-c 
-0.08947368 -0.11486749 -0.11333333 
> 
> cor(x1,x2, method = 'kendall')
[1] -0.1148675
> pcaPP::cor.fk(x1,x2)
[1] -0.1148675
```

So it seems that the `stats:cor` function with the `method='kendall'` calculates the tau-b coefficient.